# Checking if a vector field is conservative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, vector-fields

I have three different vector fields and I want to check if they are conservative:

$$1)\space \space\vec{f}(\vec{x}):=\frac{1}{||\vec{x}||}\vec{a}, \space \space D=\mathbb R^2 / (\vec{0}), \space \space \vec{a}=(a_1,a_2)$$

$$2) \space \space \vec{g}(x,y)=(\frac{x}{y^2-x^2},\frac{-y}{y^2-x^2}), \space \space D=[(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|\space y>|x|]$$

$$3) \space \space \vec{h}(x,y,z):=(2xz+y \cos (xy),\space x \cos(xy), \space x^2), D=[(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 | \space x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1]$$

I just learned/looked up the following on khanacademy:

1. A vector field $\space \vec{f} \space $ is conservative $\iff$ $\underbrace{\int_{\gamma_2}\vec{v}(x) d\vec{x}=\int_{\gamma_1}\vec{v}(x) d\vec{x}}_{\text{Path independent}} \iff \underbrace{\oint_{\gamma}\vec{v}(x) d\vec{x}=0}_{\text{conservation of energy}}$
2. If my vector field $\vec{v}$ is the gradient of some scalar field $V$ i.e $\vec{v}=\vec{\nabla}V \implies \vec{v}$ is conservative.

I understand what all of these things mean and how they were derived but I am somehow unable to properly apply them. Can someone maybe show me in a simple example how you would show that a vector field is conservative (doesn't have to be one of the fields I mentioned).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use point 2 above: try and find a scalar function which has x derivative $\frac{x}{y^2-x^2}$ and y derivative: $\frac{-y}{y^2-x^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check your question 2 and 3, you can use the theorem:

If $f=P i +Q j$ is a vector field over a simply connected and open set $D$, it is a conservative field if the first partial derivatives of $P,Q$ are continuous in $D$ and $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$.

This is 2D case. For 3D case, you should check $\nabla \times f=0$.

For your question 1, the set is not simply connected. But since $\nabla \times f \ne 0$, it can be easily checked that it is not conservative.

If $\nabla \times f =0$, you can also try to find a closed curve and see if the integral is not zero. That can also tell you that it is not conservative. If all these fail, the only way to check is to try to find whether there exists an $F$ such that $f=\nabla F$.

But your answer is not correct. There shouldn't be an $F$.

Assume $f=\nabla F$, so $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{a_1}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{a_2}{x^2+y^2}$. To find $F$, we integrate $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ with respect to $x$:

$$F(x,y)=\int \frac{a_1}{x^2+y^2} dx$$

You can get
$$F=\frac{a_1}{y}\arctan{\frac{x}{y}}+f_1(y)$$
where $f_1(y)$ is a function of $y$ since your integral is with respect to $x$. Now taking derivative with respect to $y$ and equate it with $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=a_1\frac{-\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}-\arctan{x/y}}{y^2}+f_1'(y)$$

This cannot be equal to the original $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$. So there is no $F$ such that $f=\nabla F$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why shouldn't there be an $F$?

Comment: Try the typical way to find an $F$. I will edit the answer to show you.

Comment: I am so sorry. I made a terrible mistake when I copied the question. The vector field should be $\vec{f}(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{||\vec{x}||^2} \vec{a}$ I forgot the squared part in the denominator. I also wrote it down wrong in my answer because I copy pasted it but my calculations were done with the square in the denominator. Maybe my answer makes a bit more sense now. Again, I am really really sorry.

Comment: @Rzeta: I see. But your $F$ still is not correct. You can try my way to see if your $f$ will give a potential function $F$. I will change my answer.

Comment: I will try it the way you just showed me. Thanks for your patience and sorry again that I missed that.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense now. So basically I only have to integrate one component with respect to x or y and then differentiate it with respect to x or y respectively to see if it matches the other component?

Comment: @Rzeta: That is correct.

Comment: Great. I will try answer 2) and 3). Maybe you can take a quick look at them when I am done. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Rzeta: I just realized a simple fact for question 1. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just added an answer for 2 and 3 to my answer below.

Comment: @Rzeta: They are correct.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Answers for 2 and 3.

**2. $\vec{g}(x,y)=(\frac{x}{y^2-x^2},\frac{-y}{y^2-x^2})$**

If I have a vector field $\space f=P \hat{i}+Q \hat{j} \space$ then the field is conservative if $\frac{\partial P}{dy}=\frac{\partial Q}{dx}$

$$\frac{\partial P}{dy}=\frac{-2xy}{(y^2-x^2)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial Q}{dx}=\frac{-2xy}{(y^2-x^2)^2}$$

$\implies$ the vector field is conservative

**3.** $\vec{h}(x,y,z)=(2xz,y \cos(xy),x \cos(xy),x^2)$

The vector field is conservative if: $\space \nabla \times \vec{h}=0$

$$\nabla \times \vec{h}=\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i}& \hat{j} & \hat{k}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ P&Q&R\end{vmatrix}=\hat{i}(0-0)-\hat{j}(2x-2x)+\hat{k}(\cos(xy)-xy\sin(xy)-\cos(xy)+xy \sin(xy))=0$$

$\implies$ vector field is conservative

Comment: What is a primitive function to $\int_0^k \frac{x}{y^2-x^2} \partial x$?

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for you answer. The antiderivative of $\frac{x}{y^2-x^2}$ is $\frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2-y^2)$

Comment: Yep. Then remember that you need to consider an integral constant, which in this case can be a function of y.

Comment: Once you've taken that into account, just do the same for the y component, and see if it is possible to make those expression into the same function.

Comment: So just to summarize. I basically integrate the x and y components and see if there is some function that satisfies both? You are talking about the vector field 2) right?

Comment: Actually a minor sign error somewhere. But in principle you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

If $\nabla \times \vec F=0$, then $\vec F=$ conservative if the domain is simply connected.

The domain of the first example is not simply connected and thus if the curl of the vector is zero, one cannot conclude from that alone that the vector is conservative.

The domains of the latter 2 examples are simply connected.  Thus, if the curl is zero, then the vector is conservative.

Comment: This is only true if one adds additional hypothesis to the domain of the vector field, e.g. that it is star-shaped.

Comment: This might be a really stupid question but I thought $\nabla$ is an operator, so what am I "taking" the $\nabla$ of?

Comment: @Dr.MV Are you sure about that? In the first case $D = \mathbb R^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\},$ which not star shaped. It's not even simply-connected.

Comment: @Rzeta The notation $\nabla \times F$ is shorthand for the curl of $F$.

Comment: The curl is a vector operator.  It takes a vector and generates another vector.

Comment: @treble You're right. Case 1 has a domain that isn't simply connected.  Thus, if the curl vanishes within the domain, we cannot conclude from that observation alone that the vector is conservative.  I'm working on a smart phone and missed that one.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Dr.MV Is the curl defined in $\mathbb R^n$ or just $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: The curl can be defined in 2 or 3 dimensions.  In the 2-D case, the result is a vector perpendicular to the plane with component $(\partial_x F_y -\partial_y F_x)$; the $x$ and $y$ components are $0$.  So, for Cases 2 and e, check to see if $\partial_x F_y =\partial_y F_x$.